# Which model should be used to analyze repeated measures in the context of survival meta-analysis?

Tags: mixed-model, survival, meta-analysis, joint-distribution, mixed-type-data

I am in the following context: each patient has at least 2 measurements, but possibly more (up to 5 measurements), of a given biomarker. The first measurement is taken at baseline, but the date and number of subsequent measurements vary depending on the patient.
We also have for each patient, additional adjustment covariates and time to event (e.g., death). This is a meta-analysis.

I'm looking for a way to analyze how the biomarker varies and its impact on survival; knowing that the evolution of the biomarker is censored as soon as the patient is operated on (this is done at one time or another for all patients) and that the censoring of the observation of the biomarker occurs before the censoring of the event of interest (for example, the death).

We hypothesize that the way the biomarker varies has a strong prognostic impact on survival and we would like to be able to identify “slow responders” (patients whose biomarker varies slowly) to be able to change treatment quickly.
Bad responders are easily identified, as are good responders. But there is this intermediate category that must be identified, perhaps with a threshold, so that the clinician can adapt the treatment in the first weeks. Several alternatives are possible, the slope of evolution for example?

For the moment, we used a Landmark analysis up to 4 weeks, then we put the measurement in a Cox model, with an arbitrarily chosen threshold based on the slope of the evolution but this does not give satisfactory results and we were not able to validate our results.

Any idea of the model I can use for this problem?
A joint model for repeated measures?
The ultimate goal is to identify this category of “slow responders”, these patients who present a characteristic evolution of their biomarkers associated with poor survival.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!